# Is there a way to screen share and have two mouse cursors (one for *each* users mouse)

Tags: mouse

Pairing without this is hard.  Turns into mice wrestling once u really crank it up.

Would like to be able to see two mice and know which is which, e.g. different colors. Then I can do mentor-student pairing with mentor 'pointing' to stuff and student having own control and clicking

Ideally with option for shared (1 cursor) vs non-shared (two cursors)

Comment: Are you asking to do it on one screen with two inputs, one computer with two users, and two mice?

Comment: Two cursors (updated) ty

Comment: Found this, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X,  and this, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/MPX . There are some more.